# Error: "Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key." How to sign apk/aab using Google provided signing information

Tags: android, android-keystore

While uploading my second app project to PlayStore, I got the following error while upload .aab file for a new release:

[image]

> "Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that
> your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again.
> Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with
> fingerprint: **:**:**:**:**:** "

What I did was use my first apps singing key/ my old keystore file and used this keystore file inside Android studio "build-> Generate signed bundle/apk" to generate my aab file.

Inside PlayConsole, I have checked `"Let Google manage and protect your app signing key"` so I think, now Google is also keeping this keystore file safe.

When inside Google PlayConsole, I visit `"Release > Setup > App integrity"`, I can see that there is an upload certificate and SH1 certificates but this information is different from previous apps keystore.

What I don't understand is why fingerprint of the previous app and it's alias is different from the current one?

I can download this Google managed certificate file from PlayConsole but I cannot use this certificate file to use as a "keystore" to sign my apk/aab file.

I have been reading answers on different forums but none of the solutions worked for me.

Comment: What tripped me up was we changed the "slug" in app.json to uppercase. Once we changed it back it worked.

Comment: watch this video to reset your upload key 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFisYP3NPuQ

Comment: Is this issue resolved if it can you please post your answer

Answer (score 8):

Finally after two days of trying different options, I was finally able to solve the problem.

What I did was delete my project from PlayConsole and tried to start things over once again.

What I found out is

> "Let Google manage and protect your app signing key"

was not the correct option to consider for me, if I want to use my old keystore file.

[image]

When setting your app for the first time in the PlayConsole, when you click on

> "Manage app signing"

you are presented with following options:

```
1. Let Google manage and protect your app signing key (recommended)
2. Use the same key as another app in this developer account.
3. Export and upload a key from Java keystore.
```

[image]

In order for you to use your previous projects/apps keystore file for signing apk/aab file, you need to check the second option.

Once, I checked this option, I was finally able to upload my app to playstore succesfully.

Answer (score 7):

your need to change code

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
```

to

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

Comment: Exactly what was my problems cause. Sometimes such small things go unnoticed

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. But in my case I've lost my keys when I've changed my computer. And I wasn't able to publish new app in Play store, while still getting this signing error.

**This is what helps me:**

1. I've generated new upload key and keystore in Android Studio, using this procedure - [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing?hl=tr#generate-key)
2. in Google Play Console I've started new upload of app
3. when choosing "Manage App Signing" I've selected **option 3** (*Export and upload a key from Java keystore*)
4. I've done all the steps described there:

   - download PEPK
   - in folder where I've dowloaded PEPK I've run java command with credentials (key store path and key alias) from newly generated keys in Android Studio
   - script asked me for password for newly generated key store and key
   - I've uploaded generated by script zip file
5. I've uploaded new app to Play store, no more error with wrong signing

I hope it helps someone, it tooks me 3 days to find this solution :)

Comment: Did you found any solution for the same? because I am also facing this issue.

Comment: Can you please help me with the 4th step? I generated the key using [this link](https://docs.expo.dev/app-signing/local-credentials/#android-credentials), so I'm missing some of the info I need to replace in the script. I think I only have the signing key and not the upload key. Play Console is not accepting the uploaded zip.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new application, too.

However, haven't changed anything related how to manage the app signing.
Instead, I've cleared the credentials  by running `expo build:android --clear-credentials` and then selected the option `Generate new keystore` when `Expo CLI` has asked `✔ Would you like to upload a Keystore or have us generate one for you? If you don't know what this means, let us generate it! :)`.

Answer (score -2):

What I did was deleted the project from Play Console and started over. I have successfully upload the app in play console.